# CHanging @FocusState on searchable doesn't make it focused

Tags: swiftui, focus, searchable

When the search becomes active i get a callback with `.onChange(of: isFocused`

but setting `isFocused` to false doesn't make the search inactive

```
struct MainSearchable: ViewModifier {
    
    @State var searchText: String = ""
    
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .toolbar)
            .searchSuggestions {
               ...
            }
            .onChange(of: isFocused, perform: { newValue in
                print("FOCUSED")
            })
            .onSubmit(of: .search) {
                ...
            }
            .focused($isFocused)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NavigationStack Searchable .focused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75137568/navigationstack-searchable-focused)

Comment: nice hint, but doesn't help, since the enviromental variable is read only